# Align div content using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need one div which should be aligned to right on desktop view, but when it comes to responsive, then it should aligned to left or center.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-right">Name:</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here div for label 'Name' is my target.

My test platform, please change the view to mobile view [here](http://www.bootply.com/D1iA2zueCA)

In desktop view I need the div content on right side(near to textbox). I have used 'text-right' to achieve this(this may not required).

> [image: Blockquote]

In mobile view(below img) the div content is on right side(this because of 'right-text'). But I need it in left side.

[image]

Without 'text-right', it would be like(below img), in my code I added 'text-right' in order to make it on right side(which may not needed).

[image]

**Target**: I need the div content on right side for desktop view, when it goes to mobile view I need it in left side. **Please ignore the text-right in my code**

Comment: By "on responsive" do you actually mean on "mobile"?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/tn1vPYIM6qcEx8MgKntK?p=preview

Comment: check this plnkr . @Skelly

Comment: @Skelly yes in mobile.

Comment: And why here negative?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a media query, in this example I'm assuming it would be positioned absolute.

```
.container{
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
width: 400px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {

.container{
right: auto;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your code, but target div moved entirely to right on desktop view. Please take a look [here](http://www.bootply.com/J9h6eJLGqK). My target div should be on right side(near to textbox). I need it on left side if I go for mobile view.

Comment: Ah you did say left of center but if you want it to be left just change the left value from 50% to 0px and remove 'margin-left: -200px;'

Comment: Thanks, this worked on mobile view(I got the label in left side). But in desktop view, initially if you see the label inside div would be in left side, I need it in the right side.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4 ">Name:</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this. :)